# Camera rotation issue Libgdx

Tags: java, android, camera, rotation, libgdx

I have a OrthographicCamera and I want to rotate 90° it, but when I rotate it seems to be shifted more to the right.

Before rotation:
http://postimg.org/image/4ojldia8t/

After rotation:http://postimg.org/image/dul66z2rv/

The setting up of the camera is this:

In the create method:

```
//map is an object of my personal class that wraps tiledmap class
this.renderer=new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(this.map.getMap());
this.camera=new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
this.camera.translate(mappa.getMapPixelWidth()/2, mappa.getMapPixelHeight()/2);
this.camera.update();
view=new StretchViewport(map.getMapPixelWidth(),map.getMapPixelHeight(), camera);
flag=false;
```

In the render method:

```
if(!flag) {
   flag=true;
   camera.rotate(90);
}

this.renderer.setView(this.camera);
this.renderer.render();
this.camera.position.y+=1;
this.camera.update();
```

Is that wrong?

thanks for your time

Comment: remove the IOS tag and add LIBGDX, it will help you.

Comment: ok thank you, I'd put it, because it has been suggested that the system

Comment: you said you're rotating, but that doesn't look like a 90° rotation at all. rotating in 90° would make the "thinner part" of the "cross" be on the bottom. Instead, it looks like you're just "shifting" the position of the cross.

Comment: and what am I doing wrong? I applied camera.rotate thinking that made the rotation of the camera, maybe it is not so?

Comment: here are other two screenshots where probably you understand the situation better:                                                        Before rotation: http://postimg.org/image/tc9jpq9zr/
After rotation:http://postimg.org/image/rnq6svvrr/

Comment: Try to update projection matrix again on batch. That might work.